# VS Team System 2008 web test - webserver requires domain credentials

Tags: load-testing, web-testing

I'm writing some load tests against a restricted web server on our local domain.  The webserver requires entering network credentials to be able to access sites on the server. How do I automate my network login?  Again, this is a server login, not a website login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  This MSDN ariticle explains how to set credentials for a web site that uses basic authentication or Integrated Windows authentication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182548.aspx